# Solid div over transparent text

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to have a solid div over a transparent text? A have div that hides/shows on mouseover a certain element. But the transparent text in the background messes with the div content. I want to make the div solid over all the background content. is this possible with CSS?

Comment: You might want to provide the code that you have so far. Yes, it should be possibe and it shouldn't require much change from what you already have I expect so paste what you have and people can tell you what needs changing. Using http://jsfiddle.net/ or a similar tool can help even more (though if you use this put the code in the question and then a link to jsfiddle - don't *just* use jsfiddle).

Comment: If the elements have relative, absolute or fixed positioning you can use the `z-index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in using of [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) CSS attribute.